# Google Form Submit Event: Where to place the Event Handler (Sheet trigger vs Form trigger) to save EditResponseUrl in the row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Could you please explain how and which trigger to use (where to place my Script) - Form submit event in the Form, or Form Submit event in the (Responses) Spreadsheet.
What I want to use (This is available in the Form script) :

```
var timestamp = event.response.getTimestamp();

var responseUniqueId = event.response.getId();
//The same:
//var responseURL = formResponse.getEditResponseUrl();  
//var responseUniqueId = responseURL.split('edit2=').pop();
```

This available in the Spreadsheet script:

```
event.range.getRow()
```

I want to get a row and to add the responseUniqueId there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest adding it in the spreadsheet for no other reason than that's where I usually add my scripts. The following code adds the Form response ID to each form submission as it comes in:

```js
function getResponseId() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('yourSheetName');
  var formUrl = sheet.getFormUrl();

  // Open the form to access the responses
  var responses = FormApp.openByUrl(formUrl).getResponses();

  // add the last form response ID to the last row in the sheet
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 3).setValue(responses[responses.length - 1].getId());

}
```

You need to add the `On Form Submit` trigger via the GUI in the Script Editor in addition to this code.